# In my Meteor app, only in Firefox deletion of selection text makes the browser go back to previous url

Tags: meteor, quill

I have a really weird issue that only happens in Firefox.

I am writing a Meteor App and am using the Quill Editor. http://quilljs.com/

I do not think it is necessarily the Quill Editor since I cannot reproduce the issue on the example they have on the site.

So when you type in the text box, then select your text and click delete, the browser redirects back to the previous url! It is such a terrible experience when you delete text and your browser just jumps to another page. This only happens in Firefox too, in Chrome and Safari it seems to be stable.

What is the deal? Here is the code for the quill editor...

```
Template.quillNote.rendered = ->
  self = @
  # This variable is used to stop updating the template when you are the one updating it
  self.noUpdate = false
  # If currently saving then push function into a queue to call later
  self.saving = false

  #Initialize Editor
  @editor = new Quill(@find('.quill-editor'),
    modules:
      'authorship':
        authorId: Meteor.user().username
        enabled: true
      toolbar:
        container: @find('.quill-toolbar')
      "link-tooltip": true,
      'image-tooltip': true
    theme: "snow"
  )

 self.editor.on 'text-change', (delta, source) ->
    if source is 'user'
      # Do not update screen while user is typing
      self.noUpdate = true
      saveDraftCallback()
```

Comment: Someone in Mozilla thought it's a good idea to use 'delete' as a back button by default, so this is a common problem now. Calling `event.preventDefault()` in the correct place should prevent it, though I don't know which place is correct for Quill.

Comment: Thanks, yah I found out later it was function built into firefox. And for some reason the way it is integrated into meteor causes it to go back even though the text box is in focus. I used a global to detect the delete keypress on all pages and only allow default function if it is in input field, etc..